# yandex mail not sending with smtp

Tags: python-3.x, smtp, yandex

I have a custom email
`mail@mycustomdomain.ru` which is delegated to mail.yandex.ru
This is my smtp settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'ssl://smtp.yandex.ru' # mail service smtp
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mail@mycustomdomain.ru' # email id
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '8324234LO2' #password
EMAIL_PORT = 465#
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'mail@mycustomdomain.ru'
```

But the email is not sending. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'ssl://smtp.yandex.ru' # mail service smtp
```

To:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru' # mail service smtp
```